# How to properly handle signals in C

Tags: c, signals, handler, sigint

I have really really simple program in C, let me cope paste it from internet there:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
void sigint_handler(int dummy)
{
    printf("SIGINT HANDLED!\n");
    signal(SIGINT,sigint_handler);
}

int main(){
    signal(SIGINT,sigint_handler);

    kill(getpid(),SIGINT);
    sleep(1);

    return 0;
}
```

My question is, what does this line do ?

```
signal(SIGINT,sigint_handler);
```

Is it even necessary? Without this line this program works just fine and nothing changes.

Comment: Did you read "man signal"?

Answer (score 0):

`signal(SIGINT,sigint_handler);` tells the computer to call `sigint_handler` the next time your program receives SIGINT.

Comment: Sadly I think u misunderstood me. I was thinking about line in signal handler.  I know that this command is necessary in function int main, but what about this command in sigint_handler itself?

Comment: @ogarogar It does exactly what I said. It tells the computer to call `sigint_handler` the *next* time your program receives SIGINT.